# lua serialize array for UDP

Tags: arrays, serialization, lua, udp

I am trying to send a couple of pieces of data over udp via a lua script client to a node.js server.

A string var containing a string is passed to a function. Inside the function an array is being created to add 2 more strings which are id's defined outside of the function to be used on the receiving end to identify the destination of the msg.

I have confirmed that all 3 variables are defined inside the function. I then create the array bossMsg and try to send it via sendto(). I believe this is where the error occurs because I need to serialize the the array, but reading the information I am still unclear on how to do this. Isn't there a simple way to serialize the data so it can be sent via sendto()?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
PandaBoss.sendBossMessage = function(msg)

    bossMsg = {msg, g_ID, c_ID}
    socket.try(PandaBoss.UDPSendSocket:sendto(bossMsg, ip, port))

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendto` sends a datagram to the specified IP address and port number. Datagram is a **string** with the datagram contents.

So you have to serialize `bossMsg` to a string. 
The simplest way is to serialize it to JSON. Something like this:

```lua
-- https://github.com/rxi/json.lua
json = require "json"

PandaBoss.sendBossMessage = function(msg)

    bossMsg = {msg, g_ID, c_ID}
    socket.try(PandaBoss.UDPSendSocket:sendto(json.encode(bossMsg), ip, port))

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will test this tonight and respond with results. I need to adjust my code on the other end to deserialize this so I can get the variables to be able to test. Currently it was expecting an array. I was trying this `server.on('message', function(msg) {
 console.log(`${msg[0]}`);
    msg = `${msg[0]}`;
    g_ID = `${msg[1]}`;
    c_ID = `${msg[2]}`;
});`

Comment: No luck with this code. This is the error message `JSON:encode must be called in method format`

Comment: The error message gives you a tip: you should call `encode` method of your JSON lib in a different way, e.g.`JSON:encode(table)`.

Comment: I did notice eventually notice that. I corrected it and then received an error about it being a nil value. I tried creating the table dufferently, and I even printed the contents of the table, so I know it is not a nil value. Still testing but don't understand why it is saying nil.

Comment: Still not working. I have tried more ways than I can count. Every way throws an error of either a nil value or bad method. I have tried JSON.stringify, JSON.encode, JSON.dumps, JSON.loads  everything fails. Code above updated.

Comment: So a little more tweaking and it finally worked. Thanks for the help pointing me in the right direction.